# R: find the closest observation to averages

Tags: r, match, average, closest

I have a table with description statistics (means for a, b and c) per type

```
### stats
type <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l")
mean_a <- c(0,1,1,0,2,2,0,4,4,0,5,5)
mean_b<- c(4,7,8,0,3,10,5,4,7,0,1,6)
mean_c<- c(1,2,0,3,4,5,1,24,3,0,4,5)
stats <- data.frame(type, mean_a, mean_b, mean_c)
```

I have a dataset with observations of specimen for the parameters a, b and c.
Each of the specimens have a particular type

```
# data
Id <- c("ted","bert","test","john","elf","fea","goul","houl","ili","jok","ko","lol")
type <- c("a","a","b","d","f","f","c","d","a","b","k","l")
a <- c(2,1,3,2,1,2,0,1,2,1,5,5)
b<- c(1,3,4,7,5,4,5,6,5,0,1,6)
c<- c(3,5,2,6,8,5,1,5,3,1,6,6)
data <- data.frame(Id, type, a, b, c )
```

Following these two tables, I would like to get from `data` the specimen the most representative of the type following the statistics in `stats`. 
By most representative, I would like to get the one with the closest values for a, b and c to their respectives averages.

I can not find ideas on internet following 3 averages( a, b and c). Help is welcome! Ouput wanted (but not sure if ted, test and john are the closest to the averages for the types a, b and c):

```
# output wanted
Id <- c("ted","test","john")
type <- c("a","b","c")
a <- c(2,3,2)
b<- c(1,4,7)
c<- c(3,2,6)
data2 <- data.frame(Id, type, a, b, c )
```

Comment: So what would be the expected outcome in this case? (edit expected output in your question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "most representative" as you mention on its own is very vague but here is an attempt which finds the difference between the values from `data` and the mean_values from `stats` and keeps the one with the lowest average.
Since I joined the data frames before hand, you can use the `select()` function at the end of the code and modify (keep/drop variables) accordingly.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- merge(data1, stats, by = 'type')
df1 %>% 
  mutate(new = abs(rowMeans(mapply(`-`, df1[,(3:5)], df1[,(6:8)])))) %>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  filter(new == min(new)) %>% 
  select(-new)

#Source: local data frame [7 x 8]
#Groups: type [7]

#    type     Id     a     b     c mean_a mean_b mean_c
#  <fctr> <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1      a    ted     2     1     3      0      4      1
#2      b   test     3     4     2      1      7      2
#3      c   goul     0     5     1      1      8      0
#4      d   houl     1     6     5      0      0      3
#5      f    elf     1     5     8      2     10      5
#6      k     ko     5     1     6      5      1      4
#7      l    lol     5     6     6      5      6      5
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more what is `mapply(`-`, df1[,(3:5)], df1[,(6:8)])))`? Is it to pselect the relevant column you want in the output?

Comment: Got it, it works perfectly with editing `df1[,(3:5)], df1[,(6:8)])))`to the good columns numbers

Comment: @Floni the `mapply` maps the columns of interest one on one so `df1[,3]` with `df1[,6]` and so on

Answer (score 1):

```
require(dplyr)

inner_join(stats, data) %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(diff = sum((a - mean_a)^2,
                    (b - mean_b)^2,
                    (c - mean_c)^2)) %>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  filter(diff == min(diff)) %>% 
  select(Id, type, a, b, c)



#       Id  type     a     b     c
#   <fctr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    ili     a     2     5     3
# 2   test     b     3     4     2
# 3   goul     c     0     5     1
# 4   houl     d     1     6     5
# 5    elf     f     1     5     8
# 6     ko     k     5     1     6
# 7    lol     l     5     6     6
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Chosen a quadratic measure for the distance, you might want to adapt that to whatever distance measure you prefer:

```
data$dist <- (data$a - stats[data$type, "mean_a"])^2 + 
             (data$b - stats[data$type, "mean_b"])^2 +
             (data$c - stats[data$type, "mean_c"])^2 
closest <- which.min(data$dist)
print(paste0("Closest is number ",closest, ": ",data[closest, "Id"] ))
```

Comment: A quadratic measure may be fine but you complete ignore the grouping information (`type`) in your answer

Comment: @docendo discimus  When I made up my code. the original poster had not yet replied to Sotos request for the expected output. My approach can be extended to give not one result but one result for every group. However, when I saw the expected output added, there already was an accepted answer.